# pdf download not working on Android with cordova inappbrowser

Tags: rest, api, pdf, inappbrowser

In my cordova inappbrowser app, pdfs can be downloaded by calling a RESTful service that streams the content to the user's browser (see html snippet below). This works fine on iOS and using Google Chrome directly on Android but not when doing it through cordova inappbrowser. Clicking on the link doesn't do anything. I've tried many of the suggestions here including using gview but no result.

The tag in html is an href (I tried using window.open as well) that evaluates to something like https://xxx/member/get_pdf/217521359ashr868af6as. Using target='_blank' (tried _system also)

where the value after get_pdf is a guid (value above is not the real guid)

The google viewer workoaround that many people propose works fine with a physical pdfs but my files are streamed back from the service above and gview doesn't recognize it as a pdf and shows error 'preview not available' and its not an option to store them physically. Is there some specific header to set to make gview recognize the streamed response as a pdf? I set content_type, Content-length, tried adding Content-disposition with a filename also. No go.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks,
Patrick